# About svproc documentclass

Tags: document-classes, documentation

I am supposed to submit my paper to conference, whose proceedings will be published by Springer in Lecture notes in Network and Systems(LNNS). But the said latex file is not running. It says svproc.cls not found. How to proceed further?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: type svproc.cls in to google and the first hit (at least here) is the page at Springer's website telling you how to get the files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle to check if its work  with donwloaded `svproc.cls`file.

Comment: @Bobyandbob that would be a different question, not about installation.

Comment: The files may be obtained from ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svproc/  (and at least initially can just be placed in the same directory as your document)

Comment: Fun fact: The file `ProcSci_TeX.zip` linked from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/conference-proceedings/conference-proceedings-guidelines contains `author.tex` referencing to that documentclass, but not the documentclass itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a stale question but for the benefit of others who visit this question in future, check if you have styles folder. If it does exist, the `svproc.cls` is most probably in that folder only. Link the class file using the command `\documentclass{./styles/svproc}`

Answer (score 0):

Actually what happen, in your folder svproc.cls file is not exists thats why it say like this :

```
! LaTeX Error: File svproc.cls not found.
```

To resolve this issues just import the svproc.cls file on your working folder.

And code for the svproc.cls file will be found from https://github.com/rknaebel/report-template/blob/master/svproc.cls

Hope it wiil help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple error because sproc.cls file is not found.
First check it is in the same place in the working directory then use

```
\documentclass{svproc}
```

If sproc.cls file in the other directory then check path of directory. then use

```
\documentclass{../styles/svproc}
```